# SQL query based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Basically I have 2 tables.  1 table has a list of two (important) columns.  The general idea is that items in column 2 cannot be sold in combination with items in column 1.  It is essentially a set of rules to determine correct billing combinations.  The table looks similar to this:

```
col 1   ;  col 2
-----     -----
  a     ----    b
  a     ----    h
  a     ----    d
  b     ----    f
  b     ----    z
  c     ----    z
  c     ----    d
  c     ----    b
```

Items in column 1 *can't* be sold with items in column 2.

the second table is essentially an "orders" table.  There are transaction numbers, and line numbers for each transaction.  on each transaction line there is the item sold.  There are commonly *many* items sold per transaction.    The table is set up similarly to this:

```
trans # ;    trans line  ;   item
-------     -----------    -----
12345    ----       1    ----        a
12345      ----     2      ----      b
12345       ----    3    ----        a
45678      ----     1   ----         z
45678       ----    2      ----      f
```

What I am trying to do is to take all of the transaction data, and reconcile it with the data on the list of inappropriate item combinations.  As you can see, transaction 12345 breaks the first rule because 'a' is being sold with 'b'.  This is the general idea.

Comment: In the first table will it have a row to indicate "a cant be sold with b" and another row to indicate that "b cant be sold with a"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM orders ord1, orders ord2, conditions con 
WHERE ord1.trans = ord2.trans 
AND ord1.item = con.Product1 AND ord2.item = con.Product2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is kind of solution
name the first table INCOMPAT and the second table ORDERS. 
below query will give you the result, however in your actual database you may need some changes:

```
select o1.item + '@' + o2.item
from orders o1 full join  orders o2 on o1.orderid = o2.orderid
where exists (select * from incompat i where o1.item + '@' + o2.item = i.col1 + '@' + i.col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just use a EXISTS clause.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  Trans AS Trans1 
JOIN Trans AS Trans2 ON 
  Trans1.transNb = Trans2.transNb 
WHERE CONCAT(Trans1.item, '|', Trans2.item) IN 
  (SELECT CONCAT(item1, '|', item2) FROM xCombination)
```

If COUNT is different than 0, then you have an invalid combination in the order.

Basically we do a cartesian product of all the items in the same order with Trans1 and Trans2.  We then concatenate every combination of two items in one string with a separator.  If a string can be found in the xCombination table then there is something wrong in that order.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d619a/1).

Comment: this is probably going to be 70% similar to what I end up doing.  this is a great start.  there are a couple issues though- first is that this counts 2 errors, where there is really 1.  i suppose that means it double counts everything, which could just be fixed by dividing by 2 but it is still a little messy.. second, and more important, if there are more than 2 transaction numbers this will not work.  IRL there are manyy more.  sometimes 90+.  I like the concatenation approach, but i may have to use a FOR XML to concat the rows together w/o having to do a join or a pivot

Comment: There are 2 errors in the order 12345 since there is twice the combination ab.  Also why do you say it won't work for multiple transaction numbers?

Comment: select com.id, a.transNb, a.item, a.t2
from
(SELECT 
  trans1.transNb, trans1.item, trans2.item as t2
FROM 
  Trans AS Trans1 
JOIN Trans AS Trans2 ON 
  Trans1.transNb = Trans2.transNb) a
left join xCombination com on a.item = com.item1 and a.t2 = com.item2
where com.item1 is not null

Answer (score 0):

You can list all possible pairs in a transaction by joining transactions by their id. Then check if any pair violate the rule

```
select distinct a.id
from transactions a
join transactions b on a.id = b.id and a.line_num <> b.line_num
join inappropriates c on a.item = c.col1 and b.item = c.col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Select query:

Code to create table and insert values

```
Create Table InvalidCombos(item1 int, item2 int)

Create Table TransactionInfo(transactionId int, item int)

Insert Into InvalidCombos Values(1,2), (1,8), (1,4), (2,6), (2,26), (3,26), (3,4), (3,2)

Insert Into TransactionInfo Values(12345,1), (12345,2), (45678,26), (45678,6)
```

Here is the select statement with the results:

```
Select ic.item1, ic.item2, transinfo.transactionId From invalidcombos ic 
  INNER JOIN ( 
    Select ti1.transactionId, ti1.item as item1, ti2.item as item2 
      From TransactionInfo ti1 
      LEFT JOIN TransactionInfo ti2 ON ti1.transactionid = ti2.transactionid 
      and ti1.item <> ti2.item
    )
    transinfo ON (transinfo.item1 = ic.item1 AND transinfo.item2 = ic.item2)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a self - full join on table 2, to get all the combinations in each order. Then simply inner join that to table 1.

```
select * into #t1 from
(
    select 'a' as col1, 'b' as col2
    union
    select 'a' as col1, 'h' as col2
    union
    select 'a' as col1, 'd' as col2
) q


select * into #t2 from
(
select 1 as trans, 1 as line, 'a' as item
union
select 1 as trans, 2 as line, 'b' as item
union
select 1 as trans, 3 as line, 'a' as item
union
select 2 as trans, 1 as line, 'z' as item
union
select 2 as trans, 2 as line, 'f' as item
) q

select o.* from #t1 as v
inner join
(
    select distinct a.trans, a.item as item1, b.item as item2
    from #t2 as a
    full join #t2 as b on a.trans = b.trans and a.line <> b.line
) as o on v.col1 = o.item1 and v.col2 = o.item2
```